# EasyTableView cell set value only once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm using EasyTableView in my project. And I want in first display of view use some methods and other methods in next displays:

```
- (void)easyTableView:(EasyTableView *)easyTableView setDataForView:(UIView *)view forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WCTableUserView *userView = (WCTableUserView *)view;
    if (**first display**) {
        User *user = [usersArray objectAtIndex: (NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
        userView.nameLabel.text = user.firstName;
        userView.cityLabel.text = user.cityName;
    } else {
        userView.cityLabel.text = @"Test";
    }
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**
For example, I have 12 views in table. But only 6 are visible and when I'm scrolling table view I want to check if cell was already displayed.

Comment: What do you mean by "first display"...the top cell or the first time the whole view appears on the screen?

Comment: @PhillipMills the first time view (table cell) appears on the screen :)

Comment: What is EasyTableView? And what could be easier than just using UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

check the indexpath.

```
if(indexpath.row==0) /*first*/ ....
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a suggestion?